# jsonp parseerror in jQuery Ajax request

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

I am trying to get string data from server through jsonp but it gives me the following error

> 200 parseerror Error: localJsonpCallback was not called

here is my ajax call

```
 var url = 'http://localhost:9093/Service1/Method1';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,                        
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    jsonpCallback: 'localJsonpCallback',                       
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert('normal' + result);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + " " + status + " " + error);
                    }
                });
```

In my WCF service I have the following method

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string Method1();
```

I tried using "BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped" attribute as well but gives another error "Unexpected token"

Response I see is a string "sample result"

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Inspect the JSONP response by pasting the URL into your browser's address bar. Is it what you expect?

Comment: do you have a function called `localJsonpCallback`?

Comment: yes localJsonpCallback is a global function